# Understanding how to publish to a facebook page as a page via a website (app)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have spent quite some time now trying to establish how, and then the best practise to push some data from my web server to the facebook page  created for this purpose.

I have read and understand the process of using access tokens.  I have generated an access token for myself, which can be used to post to the page as me ok.  I understand this should be used to generate the access token for the page to post as the page which is a ittle more tricky.  However, this process involves me logging in and generating an access token which seem inherently bad / inconvenient for an automated process.

For this reason i followed the guides to create an app.  I (think I have) linked the app to the page, and thus attempt to push data via the appid and secret from my php code to the page.
 When doing this I am presented with this error

```
{"error":{"message":"(#210) Subject must be a page.","type":"OAuthException","code":210}}
```

my testing code is this:

```
$data['picture'] = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";
$data['link'] = "http://www.example.com/";
$data['message'] = "Your message";
$data['caption'] = "Caption";
$data['description'] = "Description";
$data['access_token'] = $app_token2;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$app_id.'/feed';
$url1 = "https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=".$app_id."|". $app_secret ;
echo "<br>$post_url";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "$return";
```

I appreciate using the app for server initiated posting using a permanent (`ish`) secret is the correct way, but I have found very little documentation on how this process is achieved, hence this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right sorted !! FWIW the code above functions correctly, however the way it is setup on facebook leaves a lot to be desired !!!
I began messing with my app and changed its name, type (was an app linked to the page - now isnt) removed perms and also changed the domain name (removed) and all site url details (also removed). this prompted a different error msg which stated the domains did not match.  So, I readded just the app domain & site url, saved and all of a sudden my failed code started working !

Having tidied my code up a little I can now see the page access token just fine as I expected.  I just wish the facebook guides would cross reference this setup as it is not at all obvious !!!

my working code ended up as thus ($perm_url is used as one time link to allow perms via gui)

`$perm_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$appid."&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages,read_stream,status_update";`
`echo "<br>Test";`

`$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $appid , 'secret' => $appsecret ,));`
`$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();`

`$pageinfo = $facebook->api("/".$page_id."?fields=access_token");`

`$page_access_token = $pageinfo['access_token'];`

`echo "<br>Holy Grail = $page_access_token ";`

Answer (score 0):

Your $post_url is pointing to your $app_id variable, the message says it should point to a page, try getting the id of your page from the /me/accounts endpoint of the graph and putting that in there instead. Though I suspect you will need to use a page access_token (also from the /me/accounts endpoint ) to post to your page

Comment: OK, using page id i get '{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}' which makes sense.  However how do I appove the PAGE to use my app and check permissions for this are correct ?

Comment: have you granted the "manage_pages" permission? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me yes but to me (the user not page). Not sure how to query or set for the page

Comment: manage_pages should be granted for you the user, you can then get the access_token for your page. Are you sure you've changed the app in the explorer tool to be your app and not the Graph Explorer app? There's a drop down in the top right that lets you use the explorer as a different app

Comment: When I select my app and debug, it shows my app, my userid, expiry in about an hour and several scopes including manage_pages.  So from your explanation. Even with app associated with page, i need to auth using appid&secret to get access token (short term) for page. then use access token to post on page ?

Comment: I can correctly use the token generated via '$url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&client_secret=". $app_secret."&grant_type=client_credentials";' to post via the app to my personal wall using '$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/feed';'  However, I cannot do the same using $page_id

Answer (score 0):

Right, I have worked on this for quite some time and found several errors in my code, but have not answered the question fully.
For starters, you do not post to the appid as mentioned above - its just wrong.  The code for posting to userid/feed works when using an access token generated from appid + secret using

`$url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&client_secret=". $app_secret."&grant_type=client_credentials";`

this app access token is valid for as long as your app secret is.  Also, if I generate a temporary access code for ME via the graph explorer, parse me/accounts manually and use the page token in

```
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed';
```

It posts correctlly as the page.

Secondly, all server side call are required to have appsecret_spoof in them which is generated from

`$appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $app_token2, $app_secret);`

now, according to the facebook docs, a http get call to my userid/accounts should yield page access tokens for all pages the user administers (and also presumably the app).
This can also be called directly by using

```
$url3 = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$page_id."?fields=access_token";
```

so when a get is made to this address (including app access token & appsecret_spoof) all i get is 'True' ??
Likewise, when the correct call to

```
$rob1 = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/accounts";
```

I receive an error

```
{"error":{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10}}
```

OK permission issue then ! Well the documentation says that only manage_pages is required to retrieve the page token from page_id/accounts, so I trawl through lots of pages and find you can do this by calling this url

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope=read_stream
```

This throws up via facebook gui an accept / deny page for each scope (i ended up adding manage_pages, publish_stream & read_stream to my app) none of which seem to solve the problem !